# Setting Left and Right labels in UINavigationBar in a UIViewController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, xcode4.3

I am trying to add two labels - one on the left and one on the right of a UINavigationBar in my UIViewController implementation programmatically. However It doesn't show up when I run my program. I have a UIViewController that is embedded in a UINavigationController. I am using following code:

```
- (void) setTheNavigationbarView{

    CGFloat originX = self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds.origin.x;
    CGFloat originY = self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds.origin.y;
    CGFloat sizeW = self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat sizeH = self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds.size.height;

    UIView * navigationbarView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX + 1, originY + 1, sizeW - 2, sizeH - 2)];
    navigationbarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    UILabel *labelLeft = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (sizeW - 2)/2, (sizeH - 2))] autorelease];
    labelLeft.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    labelLeft.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    labelLeft.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    labelLeft.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    labelLeft.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    labelLeft.text = @"first line";
    labelLeft.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [navigationbarView addSubview:labelLeft];

    UILabel *labelRight = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(((sizeW - 2)/2 + 1), 0, (sizeW - 2)/2, (sizeH - 2))] autorelease];
    labelRight.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    labelRight.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    labelRight.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    labelRight.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    labelRight.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    labelRight.text = @"second line";
    labelRight.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [navigationbarView addSubview:labelRight];

    // set the view as navigationba title view
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navigationbarView;
}
```

I will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code and its work for me, i would only check if your frame is not bigger than every size of your navigaitonController.

Comment: It did help me esp. second suggestion. The size of self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds is w = 0 and h = 0. I changed the four lines at start of the method replacing self.navigationItem.titleView.bounds by self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame. It worked. Please edit your answer so that I can mark it as correct. Thanks again.